# Excel date formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: http://imgur.com/67pOgu8]

Could someone look at my formula and assist me with a resolution? The formula must have an error since my amount is going into column AD instead of AC like it should.  See highlighted cell.

For more clarity:
If E11 date is on or before Aug 31, 2015 then, P11 amount should be listed in column AC.  If E11 is on or after Sept 1,2015 then, the P11 amount should be listed in column AD.

I created it with a superuser guidance, and I suppose after cutting/pasting it multiple times I messed it up!  Please help me if you can.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't read images that are stored on your computer.

Comment: StackExchange uses Imgur for image storage. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Now you need to [edit] the question and tell us what is wrong with the formula. What is it supposed to do? Explain the problem.

Comment: right! you cannot read my mind, although I wish you could.

Comment: From your previous question " The date was definitely the issue. I was able to pull accurate formulas after implementing the 'text to column' advice." Does that help?

Comment: I don't fully understand the fix to my problem.  Do I need to do something additionally with text to column?

Comment: No idea. I leave it to the Excel gurus to answer.

Comment: ha! ok, thanks for looking and helping me with being clear!

Comment: I live in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that your regional settings use the DMY order, but the "date" in your screenshot is text that looks like a date in MDY order. If Excel cannot interpret the text as a date with the current regional settings, then the cell remains text.

When sorting or comparing text and numbers, text will always be treated as greater than a number, hence the condition in the formula in AC11 `=IF(E11<=DATE(2015,8,31),P11,"")` is false and in  AD11 `=IF(E11>DATE(2015,8,31),P11,"")` is TRUE.

To test if the cell contains a date, try to change the date format from short date to long date. Does it budge?

Here is a screenshot of the scenario where row 11 has the text that cannot be interpreted as a date in DMY regional settings, and row 12 has a real date.

[image]

Comment: You are right.  The column was text; I changed to long date, but the formula still showed false.  I also tried the custom number settings to d/m/yyyy, but to no avail no changes.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can I change my IF formula date to read mon/day/year?

Comment: The `DATE` function as YEAR, MONTH, DATE so that can not be changed. See my answer on another way to make the date recognizable.

Comment: How does the text date make it into the spreadsheet? Do you copy it from somewhere? If so, you need to change the way the data is treated when it gets into Excel. The exact technique depends on how that data is imported. That would be a different question, though. This question was about why the IF formula shows the wrong result and that has been answered, so please mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Date Local to UK for that cell. Right click on the Cell, Format Cells, then look at the screenshot below.

We're trying to make Excel understand what the data means. You want dd/mm/yyyy while Excel is currently seeing it as mm/dd/yyy. Your formula is working correctly, it is just interpreting the data incorrectly.

[image: Date Locale USA]

Comment: Ok, I did that.  Do I need to do anything to the cell with the formula in it, to refresh?

Comment: Try using 3/14/12 - fourth one down. Anything with a asterisk in front will use your computer's regional setting. If you're in the USA, it should already be set to recognize 08/13/2015 as August 13, 2015.

Comment: bummer, no changes.

Comment: last suggestion is to go E11, press F2, and edit the date without the 0 so it is 8/13/2015. The field is not being recognized as a date. :(

Comment: it worked!  Is there an easy way to edit the whole E column?

Comment: More information about my excel sheet.  After you first suggested, I had formatted the E column as date. A thing to note, is the software that I generated the worksheet from also included patient names, and titles such as Patients.

Comment: In another empty column, you can try `=IF(LEFT(E11,1)="0",MID(A1,2,255),A1)`. Then you can copy/paste special values back to the E column. This will replace all dates starting with a 0 to not have a zero any more. You might also consider exporting your medical records as CSV as it may be easier to work with instead of HTML or whatever you're working with.